# Add record to an SQL Azure table using LINQ where ID is "identity (auto_increment)"

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, azure

I am trying to pass a LINQ query in my Service1.svc.cs to add a new Asset which is an entity in my SQL Azure database. Also AstID is the PK and is set as identity in SQL Azure

I have an `OperationContract` as follows in my IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
void AddAsset(string AstName, string AstCondition);
```

and the following void in my Service1.cs

```
 public void AddAsset(string AstName, string AstCondition)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            Asset AssetObj = new Asset();
            AssetObj.AstName = AstName;
            AssetObj.AstCondition = AstCondition;
            context.Assets.InsertOnSubmit(AssetObj);
            context.SubmitChanges();        
        }
```

In my Client Application, where i'm consuming the WCF Service, i have the following:

```
public void AddAssetQuery(string AstName, string AstCondition)
        {
            Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
            proxy.AddAssetCompleted += (proxy_AddAssetCompleted);
            proxy.AddAssetAsync(AstName, AstCondition);

        }
```

and

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            AddAssetQuery("Dell PC","Mint");

        }
```

I also have a Completed void, wherein i have a MessageBox that notifies me that the action was completed. Even though, when i check my SQL Azure databse, no data is being fed. Any ideas, why?

Comment: No exceptions or anything? if you explicitly set the id, it works?

Comment: Nope no exceptions! that is what is strange!

Comment: I didnt set the id explicitly because it is identity, so i was assuming Azure might insert it automatically. Although, it wouldn't hurt to explicitly set the id. I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: Run fiddler and see what is going out on the wire. Does it send data to your service and to the azure, in turn?

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what fiddler is...

Comment: @Leonardo explicitly setting the ID doesn't work and anyway i want the id to be set automatically by SQL Azure

Comment: Fiddler is a free tool: http://fiddler2.com/ which is VERY useful for web development.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    public void AddAsset(string AstName, string AstCondition)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        Asset AssetObj = new Asset();
        AssetObj.AstName = AstName;
        AssetObj.AstCondition = AstCondition;
        context.Assets.Add(AssetObj);
        context.SaveChanges();        
    }
```

Comment: Is there one for AddObject()?

Comment: context.Assets = System.Data.Linq.Table
it doesn't have any of those definitions.

Comment: I added some breakpoints and i get the following now
hopefully i think i can figure that error - `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Asset' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

Comment: The error message gives you ewverything you need. Turn on IDENTITY_INSERT in your DB. "SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON"

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeff, but I would like the primary key to be auto inserted

I was hoping that by explicitly defining the primary key, i would be able to add a row, but turns out i can't. So i would like to add the record, where i would like Azure to define the primary key and the other columns are defined by me.
Any ideas?